# How to get render mode of any iOS application on runtime

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, mobile-application

Is there any way of knowing the render mode of an application at runtime on iOS device ?
I need to get the render mode of my running application and pass on different logic based on whatever render mode(CPU, GPU and Direct) I get at runtime but I am struggling to find any such API or method that can solve my purpose.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: In what situation can you need such a thing? The coder is the one setting up those render modes so how could he need to know which one he himself did set?

Comment: Actually I am dealing with a remote swf that doesn't have permission to parse the application XML to get the render mode due to iOS sandboxing. I use my application in all three render mode and based on provided render mode it decide what need to be done. so i am looking for a way to accomplish this. Any Help please ??

Comment: You use your app in all 3 render mode? The only way to do that is by publishing 3 times with the 3 render mode and once again the app knows which mode it renders with at publish time, a global variable can be set to the render mode and passed to any loaded swf. Are you asking about an hypothetic case? Cos what you describe can't actually happen.

Answer (score 0):

From a pure AS3 tack, you'd be limited to [wmodeGPU](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#wmodeGPU) (which still doesn't give you quite what you want), however, with Air you have access to [NativeWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html) classes.  That said, everything I've read on it seems to indicate this is an init state only property, and not something you can read out of your NativeWindow.

Try [stage.nativeWindow.renderMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindowInitOptions.html#renderMode)?

Comment: Thanks Atriace, but I guess NativeWindow API is not supported on mobile device its desktop specific. Is there any way of using it on iOS ?

Comment: Well, I'll be jiggered; it isn't supported.  Honestly, this is outside my experience.  I think you're up a creek without a paddle.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS789ea67d3e73a8b24b55b57a124b32b5b57-7fff.html